# CLB score of my IELTS score

Tags: canada, ielts

I took the IELTS test.

I scored:

- 7 in listening
- 5 in reading
- 6 in speaking
- 6 in writing

What will be my CLB score??

Answer (score 1):

[This Canadian government page](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/standard-requirements/language-requirements/test-equivalency-charts.html) contains a chart showing the equivalent CLB scores for various IELTS scores. Here's the chart:

[image]

Thus:

```
  IELTS 7 Listening is CLB 7 to 8

  IELTS 5 Reading is CLB 6

  IELTS 6 Speaking is CLB 7

  IELTS 6 Writing is CLB 7
```

I don't know if or how Canada averages or combines the individual scores into a single number.